# How to name each item in a dynamic form

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a MySql table:

```
id   concept
-------------
1    item1
2    item2
3    item3
```

I try to generate this table dynamically:

```
<form action="extern.php" method="post">
<?php  
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM MyTable');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>

<input type="text" name="<?php echo $row["concept"] ?>"value="<?php echo $row["concept"] ?>"><br>

<?php 
}
?>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

This gives in the source of the html:

```
<form action="extern.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="item1" value="item1"><br>
    <input type="text" name="item2" value="item2"><br>
    <input type="text" name="item3" value="item3"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="send">
</form>
```

My questions are:
- When I try to make the dynamic form in the hmtl, what "name" should I use? I mean I cannot use a static name as it can be a lot of values in the database. And it must be a value that the php can use later.
- How can I capture that value in the php?

```
$concept = $_POST["something"]; // how should I do this var?
```

Comment: @t3chguy I'm not sure why you're linking that question, they aren't asking the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use square brackets in the name attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="concepts[<?php echo $row["id"] ?>]"value="<?php echo $row["concept"] ?>">
```

And then check for a specific id for example:

```
$allConcepts = $_POST["concepts"];

$concept1 = $allConcepts[0];   // Example accessing a specific input
```

You can iterate through the *allConcepts* array afterwards to handle all inputs dynamically.

To summon up: if you use square bracket like *name="myArrayName[x]"* PHP maps the data to an array nicely and you can access the entries through $_POST['myArrayName'][x]

Comment: This works well. Just to explain if someone reads this. If I understand well the key here is that you can put in name=anyName[] and this will convert what it is in the value to an array.

Comment: In this specific example $concept1 = &allConcepts[1] As Mark puts the id inside the [], id begins with 1 (and not with 0 like most arrays)

Comment: Nice to hear it works. I updated my answer to clarify a bit further.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<form action="extern.php" method="post">
<?php  
    $result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM MyTable');
    $cntConcept=1;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $row["concept"].$cntConcept ?>" value="<?php echo $row["concept"] ?>"><br>
<?php 
    $cntConcept=$cntConcept+1;
    }
?>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

And While retrieving

```
$varname="";
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    $varname = "something".i+1;
    $concept[i] = $_POST[$varname];
}
```